# Let $K < G$ and assume every left coset $gK$ with $g \in G$ is equal to some right coset $Kb$. Show $K$ is normal to $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Note that $b \in G$ is some suitable element of $G$.

Proof:
If $gK = Kb$ $\implies$ $gk = kb$ for all $g \in G$ and some $b \in G$.
Then we may write $gkg^{-1} = kbg^{-1}.$

That's what I have at the moment, and I am stuck. I believe what needs to be shown is that $gkg^{-1} \in K$, while working with the fact that $gk = kb$ for some $b \in G$.

Just a simple hint would be nice, I do not need a complete proof. Thanks for assistance!

Comment: Hint : if $gK = Kb$, then $Kb$ must contain $g$ ; how many right cosets contain $g$ ?

Comment: All of them? I know that {$ aH : a \in G$} is a partition of $G$...

Comment: Well, precisely : in a partition of a set $G$, a given element $G$ is in exactly one part.

Comment: So we conclude that $ g = Kb$?

Comment: That does not make sense ; $g$ in an element of $G$, and $Kb$ a subset. Try to show that the only right coset that contains $g$ is $Kg$, so $gK=Kg$.

Comment: I see now, thank you so much kind stranger!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true that $gk = kb$, but rather $gk = k'b$.

We also have $g = ge \in gK$ (since $e \in K$), and since $gK = Kb$, we have that:

$g = ge = k''b$.

This means $g^{-1} = (k''b)^{-1} = b^{-1}k''^{-1}$.

So...  $\ gkg^{-1} = (gk)g^{-1} = (k'b)(b^{-1}k''^{-1}) = ?$

Comment: $(k'b)(b^{-1}k''^{-1})$ = $k'(bb^{-1})k''^{-1}$ = $k'(k'')^{-1}$ = $k''' \in K$. Therefore, $gkg^{-1} = k''' \in K$ so $K$ is normal to $G$. Is this correct? Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, that's the ticket.